# Pass long list of input parameters to web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on a proof of concept using Web API to deliver report results. The only catch is that the nature of these reports involves a long list of input parameters. For example, one report requests information on employees and accepts email as the identifier. If someone has a list of 2,000 employees from Excel this can become a massive input parameter.

Ideally I'd like to let the user just paste the list into a text box, click a button, and then let my code parse the list and generate the results all in one go. I could restructure things and instead force the user to **post** their input list (saving the parms to a DB table) and then run the report.

Is there a way to handle this or should I reconsider using a Web API call in this "all in one go" manner?

Answer (score 0):

The max size of Query string is 2048 characters. This can be easily changed in a web.config file using the settings listed below.

However, I Have been told that query string length is specific to the browser as well. So I am not sure if the default character length will be enough for you.

Another solution is -

If you have a VERY big query string then you can submit your Get request as POST and you can pass an array of a class. You can also pass an array

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/reports/employeereport")]
public void Employee(CustomObject[] pos)
{ 
}
```

you can call this method as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/reports/employeereport",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pos: objectData }) ,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
    type: 'POST',
});
```